Google Spreadsheet - delete a row on Sheet2 when I edit a quantity on sheet1 to 0 and shift all items below up
Ok so I have a google spreadsheet that I am using to keep track of my inventory, I have 2 sheets in 1 file, Sheet1 has a row of my Item, Platform, Quantity, and its Region. I have the second sheet and the code to be the same as sheet1 to keep track of the Item, Platform, Quantity, and its Region.
BUT if the quantity is 0 on the first sheet, I want sheet2's whole row or line where the quantity was set to 0 in sheet 1 to get deleted and only do that on sheet2.
I have this code so far where it is updating the list from s1 to s2 and attempting to delete it but the deletion part is not doing anything, right now, in sheet 2, the value is just displayed with 0 instead of getting the whole row or line deleted.
Essentially I just want the whole row deleted in sheet2 where I set quantity to 0 in sheet1, but keeping everything as it is in sheet1 for number inputting only, only make changes to sheet2.
If possible, after deleting the entire row, in the code, can there be a way to shift all items that are below the deleted part up? This is just to get rid of empty gaps that may get in the way after deleting a row.
function deleteRowsIfQuantityZero() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
   var range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
   var values1 = range1.getValues();
   var range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
   var values2 = range2.getValues();

   for (var i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
     if (values1[i][2] === 0) { 
     sheet2.deleteRow(i + 1);
     }
   }
 }



“Delete” a row in a table base on a value of another table
You can achieve the goal of “deleting” a row if the related row from the 1st sheet is 0 using this approach.
The script below uses an array to store the values from the first sheet then pass them on the second sheet but only if the row’s Quantity column on the first sheet is not equal to 0 effectively removing the 0 quantity item on the second sheet.
To enhance the usability, you may try using Triggers. See Triggers for more information.
Sample Code
function deleteRowsIfQuantityZero() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editableSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var newUpdatedItems = [];
  var receiverSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var esRange = editableSheet.getRange(2, 1, editableSheet.getLastRow() - 1, editableSheet.getLastColumn());
  var newData = esRange.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    if (newData[i][3] > 0) {
      newUpdatedItems.push(newData[i])
    }
  }

  try {
    var clearRange = receiverSheet.getRange(2, 1, receiverSheet.getLastRow() - 1, receiverSheet.getLastColumn());
    clearRange.clearContent();
    var pasteRange = receiverSheet.getRange(2, 1, newUpdatedItems.length, newUpdatedItems[0].length);
    pasteRange.setValues(newUpdatedItems);
  } catch (e) {
    var pasteRange = receiverSheet.getRange(2, 1, newUpdatedItems.length, newUpdatedItems[0].length);
    pasteRange.setValues(newUpdatedItems);
  }
}

Sample Output after running the function
Sheet1

Sheet2

References: Class Range()
